# What is || doing in this code? and the purpose of this code is something like switch(condition) in C?

Tags: javascript

Please tell me What this code is doing? are those keys are trying to imitate Switch(Condition) syntax like in C?
and I think that || Or operator is not just comparing left and right and returning T or F, it returns left if it was true, and right if it was false I guess?!!

```
    g = (a = Object(d.b)("scheduleStore", "userStore"))(u = Object(d.c)(u = function (e) {
        function t(e) {
            r(this, t);
            var n = i(this, (t.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(t)).call(this, e));
            return n.state = {
                status: {}
            }, n
        }
  return o(t, e), _(t, [{
     {
        key: "onBook",
        value: function (e) {
            var t = this.props.scheduleStore;
            t.booking || (e.driver_id && (alert("This assignment has been booked. Reloading the page!"), window.location.reload()), t.bookAssignment(e.id).then(function (e) {
                null === e || "error" === e.status || e.status
            }))
        }
    }, {
        key: "onUnBook",
        value: function (e) {
            this.props.scheduleStore.unbookAssignment(e.id).then(function (e) {
                e || alert("Error while cancel the reservation. Reload page!")
            })
        }
    }, {
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what `||` returns because in this snippet the result of `||` is not used.

Comment: I think that Key part, somehow is like Structures in C language? this code is trying to return a structure??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` is known, together with the `&&` operator, as *short-circuiting operators*.

When using `||`, the second expression will be calculated only after the first one results a falsy value. Say we have these code below:

```js
let a = 1
let b = 2
a == 1 || console.log('A is not 1')
b == 1 || console.log('B is not 1')
```

`B is not 1` will be logged to the console.

Also, `||` will return the former (left-hand) expression's result if it is truthy; otherwise it will return the result of the latter one. Therefore if we write:

```js
result.err || result.data
```

It will return `result.data` if `result.err` is falsy (is `0` or `false` or `undefined`, etc), otherwise it will return `result.err`.

`&&` can work like a reversed version of `||`: the second expression will be calculated only after the first one results a truthy value.

> I personally don't recommend using this as a replacement of `if` statement as it may reduce code readability.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate the Key part too?
is it like a switch(condition) in C language?

Comment: @LordArthas It seems like one - but I'm not sure about what does it do exactly, since you didn't give the code of the `_()` function.

Comment: Can you help me with this, and I just like you, don't know the value of n or any other variables, you have to guess what is the logic behind this code, at least help me with basic logic, thx
return n && 417 === n.status, 200 === n.status && "ok" === r.status && (t.activeSchedule.ws && t.activeSchedule.ws.json({...

Answer (score 0):

the || operator first checks the left hand side if it was true it returns it and ignores the right hand side , In case the left was false , it checks the right hand side and returns it , if both were false it returns the right hand side as there are no more values to check . I hope this answers what does the || operator do.

Answer (score 0):

The `||` is being used to negate `undefined` or `null`.

For example in the lines:

```
this.props.scheduleStore.unbookAssignment(e.id).then(function (e) {
                e || alert("Error while cancel the reservation. Reload page!")
```

The right side of the `||` will execute if `e` is `undefined`